# amazon marketplace web service (amazon mws) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-mws

I studied about amazon marketplace from [https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/[^]](https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/%5B%5E%5D)

I want to learn more in detail about adding product in amazon using this service.

What will the steps to add product in amazon, will I required first list the products from amazon then add or can add directly(as i know we cant create new product in amazon)

The documentation is not cleared, and we have not any kind of testing environment for test.

If you have any helpful link, please provide it.

Answer (score 7):

In order to use Amazon Marketplace Webservices (MWS) you will need a [Pro Merchant seller account, an Amazon WebStore account, a Checkout by Amazon account, or an Amazon Product Ads account](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html/182-4740930-1031725#mwsSellers).  The Pro Merchant or Professional Sellers account is currently priced at [£25.00](http://services.amazon.co.uk/services/sell-online/features-and-benefits.html) or [$39.99 USD](http://services.amazon.com/content/sell-on-amazon.htm?ld=SCSOAlogin) per month. Then [sign up for MWS](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html/182-4740930-1031725#signupMWS) by clicking the **Sign up for MWS** button at [http://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/](http://developer.amazonservices.com/) (or appropriate for your region).

It is my understanding that by calling Amazon Seller Service you can get a "sandboxed" MWS account, although I've never used that.

Once that's set up, you have two options:

1. Create a tab delimited text feed with your product information (called "flat file" in the documentation)
2. Create multiple XML feeds (mostly these four: products, prices, inventory and images)

Once that's done, you use the following API calls:

1. SubmitFeed to send your data to Amazon and put it in the processing queue (you will need to call this multiple times if using the XML formats)
2. GetFeedSubmissionList to see if it was processed
3. GetFeedSubmissionResult to see if anything went wrong

If done right, using above APIs can completely automate the process of creating new products on Amazon, linking your data to existing products (by linking to the same ASINs, EANs, UPCs or ISBNs) as well as changing images, prices and inventory.

The Amazon Developer site has C# sample client code for you to play with. Other useful references:

- [Amazon Marketplace Web Service Feeds API Section Reference](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSFeedsApiReference._V388518764_.pdf)
- [Selling on Amazon Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V397584891_.pdf)

Comment: I'm using the C# sample client they provide and the important call (`SubmitFeed`) has a couple problems -- 1. the xml namespace returned by MWS errors doesn't match code, so it doesn't properly report errors, 2. it's not generating the signed url correctly (which may be my error).  Anybody else having similar issues?

Comment: @drzaus The signing should be fine - I don't use the C# library myself but lots of people do and there do not seem to be problems with it. Working with XML is a totally different issue though. Amazon does a bad job in documenting their XML formats. There is not a single source of complete and functioning XSDs on the web, so a lot is just trial and error, sorry. There are multiple questions on SO dealing with problems due to this deficiency.

Comment: As it turns out, my problem was that a previous developer used the wrong configuration service url, so it was sending to the wrong endpoint (Orders vs Feeds), which made it come back with the wrong xml namespace (which broke the error parsing), and the "signature error" I was getting was also due to it being a different endpoint (and thus probably expecting a different method encoded within the signature, or whatever).  Thought I'd share in case anyone else gets here with the same mistake.