# Permission for using Amazon Marketplace Web Service (MWS)

Tags: api, amazon-mws

I'm developing an application for a seller at Amazon, using Marketplace Web Service API (MWS). 
The seller has created an account for managing his inventory, and says that he assigned the necessary permissions.
However, clicking "Sign up for MWS" button on https://developer.amazonservices.com/ results in permission error: "Insufficient user rights." 
Can anyone clear up what permission(s) Amazon Marketplace requires for accessing their API, or at least provide a list of all possible permissions?

Comment: You need a "Pro" seller account, see this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15014370/2097290

Comment: The seller already has the "Pro" subscription, so it must be something else.

Comment: That's what Amazon says on their site: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html/182-4740930-1031725#mwsSellers  Just as a side note, not sure if this applies to you: You can only access the MWS in the market places you're enlisted to (e.g. you cannot "Sign up" on amazonservices.com if you have a UK merchant account - you will need to sign up on amazonservices.co.uk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It has actually turned out that you can't sign up for Amazon MWS from a sub-account. No such permission exists, so this must be done by the owner.