# Amazon MWS Feeds API

Tags: amazon-mws

1. I want to select some products at my store - add them to Amazon and attach to my account.
   1.1 To reach this I can use Amazon MWS Feeds API.
   1.2 And when I send few products Amazon stores in queue but appear when processed.
2. When I want to make changes with these products (title, price, description, quantity etc) I want to make these changes at Amazon too. As at 1.1 - I should use Amazon MWS Feeds API.
3. If I want to delete product - They must be deleted at Amazon too. As at 1.1 - I should use Amazon MWS Feeds API.
4. When a customer make order on my product at Amazon - I want to sync Amazon orders with order at my web store. In this case I should use Amazon MWS Orders API.
5. Also I want to sync products quantity between my store and Amazon. In this case I should use Feeds/Reports and get an Inventory Report.

Comment: So... what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to ADD,UPDATE and DELETE Products using AMAZON MWS Feed API.

Comment: Then, by all means... erm... go ahead? You'll want to use the SubmitFeed call to add and update products. There is no way to actually delete products through the API (yes, there is, but trashing all previous data is kinda a no-no), but you can set the inventory to zero which delists the product.

Comment: but when i SubmitFeed to amazon it return sucessfull response but i did not see any product in my seller account and amazon website                           
Service Response
                FeedSubmissionInfo
                    FeedSubmissionId
                        8316233554
                    FeedType
                        _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_
                    SubmittedDate
                        2013-10-31T09:47:02Z
                    FeedProcessingStatus
                        _SUBMITTED_

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check if the products exist in the Amazon catalogue.

If they are brand new you will need to look at sending the product data via XML. I send four XML files to Amazon, one for the product name, description, etc., price, quantity and images.

Once the products are in the Amazon Catalogue you can send a flat file to them to update and delete the listings. Its best just to set them to a quantity of zero so the item can be made available quickly.

The orders report and listing report will give you the data you need. As far as I am aware everything will be a three stage process,

1. Send Request
2. Check Status of Request
3. Download Report (The data will be returned in a stream which is available in the Amazon MWS Library)

Answer (score 1):

After submitting a feed, you need to wait until it is processed, then check the processing results. The order of calls is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119419/amazon-marketplace-web-service-amazon-mws-using-c-sharp/15014370#15014370)

To list items through Amazon MWS, you will need to submit multiple feeds in addition to `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423769/correct-amazon-mws-flow-for-item-with-existing-asin/17434970#17434970)  (for existing and new ASINs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use amazon feeds api provided in different languages. to add your product to amazon catalog. "https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html" hope this help more.also hre pdf is provided for developers to step by step details.